# Raster Calculator not using specified field

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, rasterization

I'm trying to do a multicriteria evaluation in ArcGIS Pro in which I rasterize a polygon using the Polygon to Raster tool and subsequently use that raster in the raster calculator to calculate the MCE. The problem now is that the Raster Calculator doesn't seem to use the value field that I put in the rasterized polygon.

Modelbuilder of the Multicriteria Evaluation:

[image: Modelbuilder of the MCE]

Polygon to Raster showing the value field "OPPERVL_st" that I want to use:

[image: Polygon to Raster]

Raster Calculator showing the formula used:

[image: Raster Calculator]

The problem here is that the Raster calculator does not end up using the "OPPERVL_st" field, but instead uses the "VALUE" field of the raster which just gives every rasterized polygon a unique value. This renders the resulting MCE useless.

Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: Name of the field in polygon doesn't matter, it always produce field Value in raster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem turned out to be that the "OPPERVL_st" field was a Text field and not a Float field. Changing this solved the problem completely.